# Does the decorator store more than one returned value?

Tags: python, function

I have the code:

```
def my_decorator(target):
    def wrapper():
        print('Calling function "%s"' % target.__name__)
        return target() # 1
    return wrapper # 2
@my_decorator
def my_target(): # 3
    print('Hi. I am the target.')
my_target()
```

I will describe what i understand about this pattern disorderly.

#3 We are passing the function `my_target` as an argument to the decorator `my_decorator`. No problems.

#1 Actually we are calling the function `my_target`.

#2 (my doubt). When we are calling the function in #1 it will print and return to `wrapper` `'Hi. I am the target.'` so `wrapper` now stores the print from `my_target` function. Then, in #2 the reference from `wrapper()` function is called. So after this calling, `wrapper` reference will run the `print('..')` set in itself function and will return the value stored before in it ('Hi. I am the target.', as mentioned in the beginning). So, the `wrapper` function `stores` two values?

Comment: my head just started to ache reading your thoughts...

Comment: ``wrapper`` *is* a normal function, in #2 you do not call it, you are just returning it. And what do you mean by "function storing values"?

Comment: I mean that when i have a function and i return something the function get the value returned and store it in some underworld (for example, an string 'hi' or a bool True) in order to use in another part of my code. Edit: Am i wrong thinking it this way?

Comment: When a function returns a value, it may or may not be stored in a *variable*, not some underworld or a function.

Comment: This could really use some clarification on your part...it doesn't read very well, and rewording it may bring more answers to this question.

Answer (score 4):

The wrapper only stores the function to call. It prints, and then it calls the function and returns the function's return value. Whatever the function does is none of its business.

Answer (score 3):

It might help you to try unpacking your example without using the `@decorator` syntax. First off, lets understand what `@decorator` does. The declaration:

```
@decorator
def func():
    pass
```

Is equivalent to:

```
def func():
    pass
func = decorator(func)
```

To make things easier to understand, I suggest doing this manually, but picking a different name for the decorated version of your function:

```
def decorator(target):
    print("In the decorator")
    def wrapper():
        print("In the wrapper")
        target()
    return wrapper

def my_target():
    print("In the target")

my_decorated_target = decorator(my_target) # this will print "In the decorator"

my_decorated_target() # prints "In the wrapper" then "In the target"
```

Note that "In the decorator" is printed when the decorator is applied to the target function, and not when the decorated function is called later. You can also still call the original function `my_target` if you want, since it's still available.